# How can I add sets of inputs on the press of a button using Streamlit?

Tags: user-interface, streamlit

I'm trying to use Streamlit to build an accessible user interface for creating more complicated JSON objects. These objects have set patterns that will require user inputs so I want to allow the user to click a button and generate these sets of inputs. [Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WCKR.png)

What I've tried to do thus far is run a function that generates the inputs on the click of a button. Here's the code:

```
def layer_func():
dictionary["key"]  = {
    st.text_input("layer Name", "Name"): {
        "source": st.text_input("Source", "source"),
        "min": st.slider("Minimum", 0,22, 0),
        "max": st.slider("Maximum", 0,22, 22)
    }
}

if st.button('New Layer'):
 layer_func()
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that when I change a value defined in the `layer_func()` It reloads the page and causes the button value to revert to `False`, which resets the interface to not show the inputs.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the page from reloading when the user changes one of the widget values, you can refactor your code to have "source", "min", and "max" as part of a [form](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form) with a submit button, e.g.:

```
with st.form("layer_func"):
    layer_name = st.text_input("layer Name", "Name")
    source = st.text_input("Source", "source")
    min = st.slider("Minimum", 0,22, 0)
    max = st.slider("Maximum", 0,22, 22)

    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
    if submitted: 
        dictionary["key"]  = {
            layer_name: {
            "source": source,
            "min": min,
            "max": max
            }
        }

if st.button('New Layer'):
    layer_func()
```